# How to indicate that my proposition implies true/false?

Tags: logic, notation

I would like to know the correct notations in logic for the following statements:

- "the proposition $\alpha$ is true (or false)"
- "the variable $A$ implies true (or false)"

Which of the following sentences are syntactically valid? And why?

| Symbol | Proposition case | Variable case |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Single arrow ($\rightarrow$) | $\alpha \rightarrow \top$ | $A \rightarrow \top$ |
| Double arrow ($\Rightarrow$) | $\alpha \Rightarrow\top$ | $A \Rightarrow \top$ |
| Long double arrow ($\implies$)<sup>[1]</sup> | $\alpha \implies \top$ | $A \implies \top$ |
| Single turnstile ($\vdash$) | $\alpha \vdash \top$ | $A \vdash \top$ |
| Single turnstile ($\models$) | $\alpha \models \top$ | $A \models \top$ |

[1] Which in LaTeX is properly named "implies".

Comment: $\alpha \vDash \bot$ reads "alpha implies the False" (double turnstile)

Comment: It really depends. Both turnstyles are probably not what you are looking for. In one of the courses I took the double arrow was used in the meta theory while the single arrow was used as part of the language. For your case I would probably use the single arrow

Comment: I think when you say that a proposition is true or false, you don't mean it's a **proposition** but its **truth value**. It is denoted with a $v$ e.g. $v(\alpha)=\mathrm{F}$. That's how I write your first sentence, and the second one I think is correct.

Comment: $\alpha \to \bot$ reads "if alpha, then False" that is equivalent to $\lnot \alpha$.

Comment: There is the [Type Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/type-theory-intuitionistic/#JudgForm) form of judgment: $A : \text {true}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha, \beta, \cdots$ are commonly used as syntactic metavariables to stand for well-formed formulas. So using *the proposition $\alpha$* is usual in a way that *the proposition $A$ would not be*. Capital latin letters $A, B, C \cdots$ are normally used as propositional variables, i.e. variables within the propositional logic.

For *the proposition $\alpha$ is true*, you can use:

- $\alpha$ is true.
- $\alpha$ holds.
- $\models \alpha$
- $\alpha$ is a tautology.

To say that $\alpha$ is provably a tautology, meaning that $\alpha$ has a proof in the relevant deduction system, you can say

- $\vdash \alpha$

*$A$ implies true* can be written as a proposition in the following way

- $A \to \top$

$A \to \top$, by itself, is a proposition. It is equivalent to $(\lnot A) \lor \top$ and therefore is always true.

*$A$ implies false* can be written as a proposition in the following way

- $A \to \bot$

$A \to \bot$ is also a proposition. It is equivalent to $(\lnot A) \lor \bot$ and is thus equivalent to $\lnot A$.